# How to tell OP the answer to their question if my answers are getting deleted and I don't have enough rating to comment?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I have a question about my Mathematics Stack Exchange post: [Coordinate-free definition of integration of differential forms?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023064/coordinate-free-definition-of-integration-of-differential-forms/4469529#4469529)

This question is answered in the book *Global Calculus* by Ramanan, Chapter 3.
I tried twice to write an answer, the first time, I sketched what Ramanan does (and also explained a few details of his approach, which I don't completely comprehend). This answer was deleted, so in my second try I just gave this reference without further explanations.

The second try has also been deleted. Now I wanted to give this reference in a comment, but  I don't have enough rating points to comment. What would be the next step now?

Comment: I think the second deletion was incorrect. Sadly, this happens, in particular, some users confuse a "link only" reference and a "textbook reference."

Comment: The first deletion was *egregiously* incorrect given the details you edited in and should obviously be reversed.  I've voted to undelete it.

Comment: A charitable interpretation of the deletion of your first answer (now undeleted) is that the voting got started before your edit that added some of Ramanan's details.  I'm not sure if any timing can be seen to support that, but it is unfortunate even if that's how it happened.

Comment: If you click through to the timeline page and the reviews, you can see that the first two delete votes from review were cast on the uneditied post, and the third (and final) delete vote came about three hours after you edited. You'll have to ask the voters why they voted the way they did, but I think the answer after the edit is fine and should not be deleted.

Comment: Thank you all for undeleting my answer and for giving me enough reputation to comment.

Comment: @user1066309 Thank *you* for following the right protocol by bringing this to our attention, and for contributing an excellent answer to MSE. The other users only did the needful, following your efforts. The votes now mean that you may alert any such user in the comments.